# ExactTarget: Access Tracking information through python API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, campaign, jobs

I've been searching extensively but still can't figure out.
On the email dashboard, I'm doing Tracking > Send. In the My Tracking folder, I see a lot of Job ID, alongside good information like "Email Sent", Unique ClickThroughRate, etc etc.

I want to create a python script that can automatically access all my campaigns/jobs and grab these numbers. Even better, if possible I'd like to drill down and get the information from Overview, ClickActivity (LinkView), etc.

How can I achieve that using the Python API? Or is there a better alternative like an automated job that directly sends the information to the EnhancedFTP?

Thanks a lot!